# Do student aid and tax-exemption qualify as "Federal financial assistance" in the sense of the Civil Rights Act of 1964?

Tags: discrimination, education, civil-rights, federal-tax-law

The [Civil Rights Act of 1964 stipulates](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/USCODE-2008-title42/html/USCODE-2008-title42-chap21-subchapV.htm) (emphasis by me):

> No person in the United States shall, on the ground of race, color, or national origin, be excluded from participation in, be denied the benefits of, or be subjected to discrimination under any **program or activity receiving Federal financial assistance.**

I was wondering:

- Does **federal student aid** make the college "receive federal assistance"? After all, it is the *student*, not the *program*, who receives the assistance.
- Many scientific institutions are [**tax exempt**](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/501); does that qualify as "receiving assistance"? After all, they are not receiving anything (as opposed to, for example, the government paying for grants etc.).

In other words, would students enrolling in colleges which e.g. refuse to enroll some students on the grounds of race (except as affirmative action!) be ineligible for student loans ? Would such an institution have to pay income taxes?